# Automating system level print dialog box

Tags: ruby, selenium, autoit

I am writing a script to automate Save as process from a webpage.

Basically there is a website on which there is a button called `PREVIEW`. The steps would be:

1. Click on preview button,on pressing that a webpage appears with all data and at bottom there is a PRINT button.
2. Now click on Print button, after that a Print dialog box appears in Mozilla Firefox.
3. After that select PDF from Name(ie Drop Down in Print Dialog Box) and click on OK button.
4. Now a SAVE AS Dialog box appears,where i need to provide the Path to save file and name of file.

**CODE**

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'win32ole'
require "au3"
require 'rautomation'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.navigate.to 'C:\Users\js830363\Documents\Userdata\GOI\New_Sahi\Ruby_Final\Demo2.html'
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout =>180)

wait.until {driver.find_element(:id,'Button1').click} #ID OF Print Button to click
//Till Here it work fine.I get a print dialog box in firefox after that I have tried with

Autoit:
#Wait for the window to exist
AutoItX3::Window.wait("Print") #The start of the title is enough to find it

window = AutoItX3::Window.new("Print")#Get a reference to it

window.activate #Bring it to the front
AutoItX3::window.controlClick("Print", "", "1057")#id of OK and Cancel Button
window.controlClick("Print", "", "1058")

Rautomation:
win = RAutomation::Window.new :title => /Opening rautomation/, :adapter => :ms_uia
win.send_keys :enter

file_dialog = RAutomation::Window.new :title => /Enter name of file/
file_dialog.button(:value => "&Save").click
```

**ERROR**

```
C:\Users\js830363\Desktop>ruby test1.rb
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in
rbuf_fill': Net::Rea dTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
         from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:152:in `rbuf_fill'
         from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
         from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
         from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
```

I am using ruby 2.0.0 and Selenium Webdriver as well as AutorIt also I have tried using reautomation but was unable to click the print button.

Comment: could you please format your text?

Comment: i tried to do it..but than it wont let me post the question :(...sorry i am new to this..Exactly what part do you want me to format?